# Showing multiple jquery image sliders on same page using php

Tags: php, jquery, slideshow

Hi I currently have a jquery image slider script that pulls images from a folder and shows them on a page.

Here is the webpage with the working image slider: http://iseeit.no/slidertest/

What I want and have been trying to figure out is to have 9 individual sliders on the same page, here is an example picture that shows how it should look like:

each of the grey boxes represents the sliders

[image]

Now I've been trying to make a new div for each slides, but I can't figure out how to do it...

Here is the index.php script:

Slideshow

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myslides').cycle({
    fit: 1, pause: 2, timeout: 100
    });
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/dynamicslides.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />


</head>
<body>

<?php
$directory = 'images/slideshow';    
try {       
    // Styling for images   
echo "<div id=\"myslides\">";   
foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
    if ($item->isFile()) {
        $path = $directory . "/" . $item;   
        echo "<img src=\"" . $path . "\" />";   
    }
}   
echo "</div>";
}   
catch(Exception $e) {
echo 'No images found for this slideshow.<br />';   
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS coding:

```
#myslides {

padding: -8px;
margin: -8px;

} 


#myslides img {

}
```

So I was wondering how I would do this? I've tried to make a new div but I don't hvae so much experience with php, so I don't think I'm doing it right...

Would love to get some feedback and some help with this.

Here is all the files that has to do with the script:
http://iseeit.no/files/slidertest.rar

Comment: use same as your code but use class instead of id

Comment: @rajeshkakawat I didn't get that to work with what I curently have... but with the scripts that Sven gave me this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question right, then you have one working slider and want more of them on one page next to each other. If so then you can do it like so:

PHP:

```
    // set the directories of the sliders you want
    $directories = array('images/slideshow', 
                         'images/slideshow2',
                         'images/slideshow3',
                         'images/slideshow4',
                         'images/slideshow5');    

    //create all the image sliders
    foreach($directories as $dir) {
        try {       
            echo '<div class="myslides">';   

            //add slides
            foreach( new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $item ) {            
                if ($item->isFile()) { 
                    echo '<img src="' . $dir . '/' . $item. '" />';   
                }
            }   

            echo '</div>';          
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            //do nothing, just skip the slider
        }
    }
```

And set the jQuery plugin for the slider on the class `myslides` like so:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.myslides').cycle({
                fit: 1, pause: 2, timeout: 100
            });
        });
    </script>
```

You can use `floats` to place the sliders next to each other. Best practice would be an `ul` with the sliders as an `li`. But i left it as an `div` for now. You can get them next to each other with this CSS:

```
.myslides {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0; //top, right, bottom, left
    width: 200px; //set the width and height of the sliders (or maybe the slider is doing it?)
    height: 400px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

**update: example code to create 3x3**

```
$directories = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7);
$i = 0;
echo '<ul>';

foreach($directories as $dir) {
    // devide $i by 3, is the outcome 0?
    if($i % 3 == 0 && $i != 0) {
        //end row
        echo '</li>';

        //are there more items for the next row?
        if($i != count($directories)) {
            echo '<li>';
        }
    } elseif($i == 0) {
        echo '<li>';
    }

    // your code
    echo 'Jeah!';

    $i++; //add one 
}

//close last element and list
echo '</li></ul>';
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Jeah!Jeah!Jeah!</li>
    <li>Jeah!Jeah!Jeah!</li>
    <li>Jeah!Jeah!Jeah!</li>
    <li>Jeah!Jeah!Jeah!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I try the solution you gave me I get this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/clients/client3/web3/web/plussmegleren/index.php on line 25.   and on line 25 there is this:                          'images/slideshow3'

Comment: I updated the code. Forgot to add `,` after the array items. I didn't tested the code btw, but it should work :)

Comment: If you check this out: you can see there are 9 slides now: http://iseeit.no/plussmegleren/ Hw do I allign it to be 3 slides in width and 3 in height? and I tried to make the padding: top: -8 left: -8, so it's in the corner, but that didn't work.

Comment: So basically I want the slides to be forced to 3x3, I think I've managed to do the corner thing correcly, I used margin: -8px 0px 0px -8px;

Comment: To fill up the total width and height is a challenge. You need to use some pro CSS stuff. Here you can find out how to fill the screen with divs: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail

Comment: It had to be padding indeed, but you don't need negative values. updated the code. An more easy solution to the 3x3 thing is to create rows with 3 sliders in them with PHP. I'll update the code with an example.